# How to change column width of a table when creating a Word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I opened a new question, because none of the answers I found here or elsewhere work for me.

I create a table using Word from C# (Office 16.0 Interop).

**My goal: To make the width of a certain column smaller, i.e. fit to its content.**

This is how I create a table:

```
var table = doc.Tables.Add(menuParagraph.Range, rowCount, 2, ref _objMiss, ref _objMiss);
table.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
table.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;

// Label
table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorGray20;
table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Label";
table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorGray20;
table.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = $"{recordItem.TextId.EnglishTranslation} ({recordItem.TextId.GermanTranslation})";
// Type and length
table.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "DataType";
table.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = $"{recordItem.DataType} (Bit length: {recordItem.BitLength})";
// Byte offset
table.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Byte offset";
table.Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = $"{recordItem.ByteOffset}";
// Default value
table.Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Default value";
table.Cell(4, 2).Range.Text = $"{recordItem.DefaultValue}";
```

None of the solutions I found so far, solved my problem.
In fact, none of it has any effect on my table.

`table.Columns[0].AutoFit();` gets ignored, has no effect whatsoever.

Same goes for `table.AutoFitBehavior(Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);`

Even if I set the width directly, it gets ignored:

```
table.Columns[0].Width = app.PixelsToPoints(100f);
```

The output is always the same. A table where each column has the same width.

[image]

How do I force a table to make one column adjust its width to its contents (and still use the whole width of a page in total).

Comment: If all questions were as well written and well formatted as this, this world would be worth living in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For auto-fitting the first column, something like this should work. It uses the [Column.SetWidth Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/column-setwidth-method-word).

```
table.AllowAutoFit = true;
Word.Column firstCol = table.Columns[1];
firstCol.AutoFit(); // force fit sizing
Single firstColAutoWidth = firstCol.Width; // store autofit width
table.AutoFitBehavior(Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitWindow); // fill page width
firstCol.SetWidth(firstColAutoWidth, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustFirstColumn); // reset width keeping right table margin
```

Comment: First of all thanks for pointing out that the first column is [1] because of the 1-based indexing in VB. Additionally, this works, but my problem was a different one. Oddly, I have to Re-Build my solution whenever I change code related to the COM-exposed Word stuff... Seems to be a problem in my configuration...

Comment: ` the first column is [1] because of the 1-based indexing in VB` -- @Exa, VB.Net indexing is not 1-based.  This is convention chosen for the Office collection types not a language constraint.  VB.Net default arrays are zero based as are the collections in the .Net library.  In regards to your _ReBuild_ issue,  are you making that statement in regards to using the _edit and continue_ feature of debugger? If so, this is likely due to `Embed Interop Type` being set to `True` for the Office interface assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with : table.Columns[0].PreferredWidth ? 
Maybe that would work.
Here is some documentation about it :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table.preferredwidth.aspx